# Is there a way to debug iTunes apps?

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode7, appium, appium-ios

i wanted to write some automated tests for an iTunes app that is not mine for a demo, but Appium says

"Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.salesforce.chatter was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer)"

The question is if there is any way i can automate tests in this app. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NO. iOS is not allowing to access(Automation) apps which are dowloaded from app store.

Automation supports app which is debug enabled[ad-hoc builds].